# Discord.js Guild ID and data do not correspond

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this peculiar problem: I read for a guild using its ID (`677199911430782978`) in Discord.js, and it returns `undefined`. Then I tried using this code to troubleshoot it:

```
client.on('guildCreate', () => {
    console.log(`Client.guilds.cache had a value added.\nAdded value:\n${client.guilds.cache.firstKey()}\nValue Amount: ${client.guilds.cache.size}`);
});
```

It logged:

```
Client.guilds.cache had a value added.
Added value:
706811476517584968 // - This is supposed to be the guild ID!
Value Amount: 1
```

I'm curious as to how the log shows another value then the actual guild ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the guild create event listener you also need to define the `guild` object.

```js
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    console.log(`Client.guilds.cache had a value added.\nAdded value:\n${guild.id}\nValue Amount: ${client.guilds.cache.size}`);
}
```